# Is it possible to work out what the filename of the index of a website is with PHP?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Take this scenario for an example:

1. User types "`http://example.com/index.html`" into my form
2. Form is sent to backend script which does `file_get_contents("http://example.com/index.html")`
3. PHP script saves the returned html to a file with the name "`site.html`" (file extension based on the extension of the given address)

Now consider this second example:

1. User types "`http://example.com`" into my form
2. Form is sent to backend script which does `file_get_contents("http://example.com")`
3. PHP script saves the returned html to a file with the name "`site.com`" (file extension based on the extension of the given address)

Clearly this method is not ideal because the file `"site.com"` is now pretty useless.

My question is, is there a way for PHP to work out what type of file it is getting?  In the second example, it could be anything from `"index.html"` to `"default.asp"` depending on the server settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the `Content-Type` HTTP header to figure out what *type* of file you are getting — but you can't find out what the filename used on the server is (or even if there is a filename), and (in most cases) both index.html and default.asp will return an HTML document.

Comment: You can probably still get the headers from a stream context, or via $http_response_header

Comment: The type of file is good enough for me, just as long as it will display correctly.  Clearly calling a php or asp file .html will make no difference at this point because I'm only fetching the generated html anyway, not the original script.

Comment: I've added some sample code that shows how the Content-Type of the file_get_contents response can be determined

Answer (score 0):

If example.com is a different server than the one PHP is running on,  you can't.
OPTION : you can bruteforce, that is trying different possible filenames (index.htm, index.html, index.php, index.asp, default.html, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Two points here:

- Firstly, no it is not possible to work out the name of the file that was served if you just requested the root of a directory. This is handled internally by the web server, and it doesn't tell the client how it was handled. Sorry.
- Secondly - surely you can just give all the files a `.html` extension if no file name was specified? In 99% of cases the default file that is served is HTML, even if it is a `.asp` or `.php` extension, all that it spits out is dynamically generated HTML. You don't get the source code, only the result.

**EDIT**

This is the best solution I can come up with for determining a sensible file extension based purely on the URL:

```
$urlParts = parse_url($url);
if (!isset($urlParts['path'])) $ext = 'html'; else {
  $pathParts = explode('/',$urlParts['path']);
  $ext = (count($fileParts = explode('.',array_pop($pathParts))) > 1) ? array_pop($fileParts) : 'html';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, anyway it will be HTML file. So always use HTML extension.

Comment: It will be an HTML file? What if I were to … `DirectoryIndex index.png index.jpeg index.gif`. It will *probably* be HTML, but you can't guarantee it.

Comment: `if(preg_match('\<body>(.*)<\/body>/')) { /* OK */ }`

Comment: — While that wouldn't actually match anything in http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml — you could have a plain text document that that matches.

Comment: Its just sugsetion. Not answer. Actualy you can have `<strong>asd</strong>` working website and parsed by browser. Web page content coulde loaded by ajax. So there is a question how much is enough? Check does file have html tags, if it does, use html ext., else, check if file header is from valid list like application/pdf(by that select extension) if no, then save as txt.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use the URL to determine the type of response you get. What you need is the [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) from the [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) response header.

You can extract this header from the automatically populated [$http_response_header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) variable. Here's an example which will get the contents of a URL, and maps the Content-Type of the response to a file extension....

```
$typeMap=array(
        'text/html'  =>'.html',
        'text/plain' =>'.txt',
        'image/jpeg' =>'.jpeg',
        #you get the idea...
);

$html=file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");

$ext='.html';//assume html, and prove otherwise....

//examine the headers
foreach($http_response_header as $hdr)
{
        list($name,$value)=explode(':', $hdr, 2);
        if ($name=='Content-Type')
        {
                #naive parse of content type
                list($type,$extra)=explode(';', $value, 2);
                if (isset($typeMap[$type]))
                        $ext=$typeMap[$type];

                //no need to look at more headers
                break;
        }
}
```